# What is the first appearance of the X-Men jet?

Tags: marvel, x-men

I'm looking for the first appearance of the X-Men jet that looked similar to the SR-71 Blackbird. I already tried googling for it, but it seems to be a very polluted keyword.

Answer (score 4):

It appears to be from X-Men #104, published in April 1977, [according to](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men_Vol_1_104) the Marvel Wikia.

It is, in fact, an SR-71 Blackbird. [The Wikia page for the X-Men Blackbird](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men_Blackbird#History):

> Professor Charles Xavier somehow gained at least one working version of the RS-150 Blackbird from S.H.I.E.L.D., after the X-Men's Stratojet had been destroyed by Count Nefaria...At some time, the Professor upgraded to the **SR-71 Blackbird**.

From [Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackbird_(comics)#Fictional_history):

> When the series resumed in 1975, the X-Men flew a strato-Jet that **resembled a larger version of the Lockheed SR-71 "Blackbird" spy plane** (hence the name), modified to carry several passengers and for Vertical Take-Off and Landing (VTOL). **Some writers have referred to this design as the "SR-73" , "SR-77", or the "SR-70"**...

Wikipedia sites "X-Men '92 #1" from May 2015 on Infinite Comics as calling the plane an SR model. It is also known as the "X-Jet."